# Zend_Acl For Specific Parts Of The Page

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, zend-acl

I know how to use Zend_Acl to allow certain resources to certain usergroups but how do i use it to allow only specific parts of the page to be shown? For example

I have a button to delete a post via AJAX on the page but i only want to show the button to Admins only. I can use Zend_Acl to block access to the controller post/delete but i can't use it to block the button from showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// in controller
$this->view->allow_delete_post = $acl->isAllowed($role, 'delete_post');
```

.

```
// in template
<? if ($this->allow_delete_post): ?>[button html]<? endif; ?>
```

Would that not do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a custom static ACL class which you can then call directly from within your view script.

Since ACL is normally handled at plugin level it means that if your visitor is seeing the view then ACL has already allowed the resource, therefor inside your view you can now do something like this...

```
     if(My_Custom_Acl::getIsAllowed('some_resource', 'delete_post_action'){
```

I did not specify the role name in the custom getIsAllowed() method, because at this point ACL is already suppose to know the user's Identity and the Role.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Although Christof gave a good solution, an alternative is to split the views. Although this starts to violate DRY, when you have about 200 different admin things/controls, it's getting heavy in the view - thus splitting the view with $this->render('view') and $this->render('edit') for permissions from the controller is sometimes easier. Then only the edit view script has the edit links. But again, it's DRY, so not optimal, but an alternative. I guess you have to weigh it up, which one is more DRY, repeating the ACL check or the stuff in 2 views...